# Getting Can't mass-assign protected attributes: address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, has-one, mass-assignment

I am getting the following in the log when I try to assign a nested attribute.  I have scanned and tried all the answers that I can find, but nothing works.

> Started POST "/admin/care_homes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-11 23:27:24 +0100
>       Processing by Admin::CareHomesController#create as HTML
>       Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"Zymx7VQU1mi+ho5T+Ups6cvHavpE4ClU6g1QFi+Y3z8=", "care_home"=>{"organisation_name"=>"", "cqc_id"=>"", "csa_id"=>"", "address"=>{"street_address"=>"", "address_line_two"=>"", "city"=>"", "county_id"=>"1", "postcode"=>""}, "registered_manager"=>"", "telephone_number"=>"", "website"=>"", "region_id"=>"1", "authority_id"=>"1", "provider_id"=>"11789", "details"=>"", "directions"=>""}}
>     User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
>
> WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: address

I have an STI of CareHome < Service.  Address is a polymorphic relationship.

In service I have:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base

  paginates_per 15

  image_accessor :home_image

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :validate => true
  has_one :county, :through => :address

  attr_accessible :organisation_name, :cqc_id, :csa_id, :registered_manager,
              :telephone_number, 
              :website, :region_id, :authority_id, :provider_id,
              :details, :directions, :home_image, :retained_home_image,
              :county, :address_attributes

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

In CareHomeController#new/create I have

```
def new
  @care_home = CareHome.new
  @care_home.build_address
end

def create
  @care_home = CareHome.new(params[:care_home])
  if @care_home.save
    redirect_to admin_care_home_path(@care_home), :notice => 'Saved' 
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :id, :street_address, :address_line_two, :city, :county_id, :postcode, :country_id, :addressable_id, :addressable_type

  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :county
```

If I add :address to the attr_accessible I get the error:

> Address(#2560574700) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2157282280)

My Rails version is 3.1.1.

I guess it must be something subtle, but I have run out of ideas to try. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reasons why you write attr_accesssible.

comment out that line and try

Comment: Because the documentation says to. I just tried taking it out and I get the same error.

Comment: I think I have found it. 

Using 
`render :partial => "form", :locals{:f => f
creates a form with field names 'address' 

If I use 

`render "form", :f => f 

Then it creates a form with field names 'address_attributes' and that works OK.

Not sure why there should be a difference?